# Fix canvas size, when it's big the draw is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, html5-canvas

When I make the HTML canvas bigger, the point I click and the point I draw is very far away. When instead the canvas is of standard size it is perfect. How can I fix it? I've tried to do it in CSS with width of 100vw; but nothing. I also tried to define it in the HTML but in any case also there the stroke is wrong with respect to the position of the mouse.

```
@import "compass/css3";

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  
    &:hover {
   span {
      display: none; 
    }
  }
}

canvas {
 cursor: crosshair;
 border: 1px solid red;
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
```

}

```
span {
  font-family: 'Georgia', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #000;
  margin-top: -40px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

<canvas id='canvas'></canvas>

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

let isDrawing = false;
let lastX = 0;
let lastY = 0;

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.clientX, e.clientY];
});

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  if (!isDrawing) return;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(lastX, lastY);
    ctx.lineTo(e.offsetX, e.offsetY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
    [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
});

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', () => isDrawing = false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseout', () => isDrawing = false);
```

Comment: I can't see you resizing the canvas anywhere. A common solution is to create a scale (newSize / oldSize), and multiply the coordinates with the scale.

Comment: Sorry, I have added my css solution that doesn't work. Can you explain better what do you mean with scale?

Comment: Noo! Don't set canvas size with CSS, you just get a blurry canvas. Use `width` and `height` attribute of the canvas instead.

Comment: Setting the width and height _attributes_ on the canvas, determines how many _pixels_ it will contain. Specifying width and height of the canvas element via CSS, _stretches_ those existing pixels, to fill the given amount of space. But the `clientX`/ `clientY` coordinates you read from the mouse events, are not stretched. So if you _do_ specify the canvas width and height via CSS, then you will need to _convert_ between those two different "coordinate systems" you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using e.clientX and e.clientY for the mouse position when you start drawing. clientX and clientY are relative to the viewport (browser window), so when you increase the canvas size, the mouse position becomes incorrect. To fix this, you need to use e.offsetX and e.offsetY instead. These values are relative to the canvas, so they will always be accurate, regardless of canvas size. So your code should look like this:

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
  isDrawing = true;
  [lastX, lastY] = [e.offsetX, e.offsetY];
});
```